# implementing search functionality in asp.net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What is the best way to implement search functionality on the website ? I have a site with ~30 subpages. What are possible options ?

I know that I can use simple SQL but what if site grows ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: _What_ do you want to search for? Text appearing on those ~30 pages? And is that text static, or generated dynamically (so what you really want to search for is content in a database or something...)?

Comment: The content would be in database (content of the pages can be changed so I think that simple CMS will keep data in sql table column)

Comment: So you want us to tell you have to search in a database? I think you need to expand your question quite a bit, tell us in more detail what you want to do, what you have tried etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably implement a google search on your site. That might be the easiest way to provide search functionality.

Otherwise look into SQL free text search, or Lucene.Net free text search.

Comment: But using google search I want be able to add styles to the search results